# update table takes long time in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE fa (    
book varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,     
PRODUCTION varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,        
VENDOR_LEVEL varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,    
BOOK_NO int(10) DEFAULT NULL,    
UNSTABLE_TIME_PERIOD varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,    
`PERIOD_YEAR` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
```

`promo_3_visuals_manual_drag` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BOOK_NO` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_LEVEL_DIST` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_LEVEL_ACV_TREND` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `book` (`BOOK_NO`),
  KEY `period` (`PERIOD_YEAR`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Index we added to column 
Index : BOOK_NO and PERIODIC_YEAR has added

we cant add unique nor primary key to both column as it has plenty of duplicate values in it.

There are 46 millions rows.

We tried partitioning to period year and catno for sub partition, but doesn't worked as it is still takes long time

When i run the update query :

```
update fa set UNSTABLE_TIME_PERIOD = NULL  where BOOK_NO = 0 and periodic_year = 201502;
```

It taking me more than 7 min , how can i OPTIMIZE the query?

Comment: Your table doesn't have any key (not even a PK). No wonder it's all slow.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes there is no PK ,bcoz there are many duplicate values in column which cannot added. do u have any suggestions in it?

Comment: There are two ways to find references to Winston Churchill in a 2,000 page book about WWII: check the onomastic index or review all 2,000 pages one by one. A database table is a very similar use case. If you think you can't use indexes, you can't afford 46,000,000 rows ;-)

Comment: I have already added index to both column book_no and period_year ,sorry i have not mentioned in questions, still it takes more time @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Out of curiosity, what meaning do duplicate rows have in your business logic? Do they represent stock units of your items?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose a query performance with just a vague textual description of an index. You should post the real `CREATE TABLE` statement as well as the execution plan (`EXPLAIN UPDATE fa SET ...`). Whatever, I had got the impression that you were not allowed to create indexes, I guess you can, can't you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  yes it is stock units items which has plenty of duplicate values like 0 ,1 ,201501 has plenty of duplicate. Explain table shows      possible_keys shows : cat_no and period_year ,key = cat_no,type=range

Comment: EXPLAIN plan tells:  Possible_key : BOOK_NO and PERIODIC_year ,  key= BOOK_NO  , type = range;

Comment: suggest me how can i optimize or change the query which will bring faster results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 2 different keys, create single composite key for both the columns like:

KEY book_period (BOOK_NO, PERIOD_YEAR)

Also, first filter the records based on the column which will return the small set of records as compare to other.
If you think BOOK_NO will return less number of records as compare to PERIOD_YEAR,  Use BOOK_NO first in where clause else use PERIOD_YEAR first and create the key accordingly.

Comment: Along with above improvement, you can try replacing charset utf8 with latin1 for the table and set with specific column if you really need that. Not sure how much effect it will make though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but things is both book_no and period_year has same set of filter and each has 500K rows. and what is the use of creating one single composite key instead of 2 key, can u suggest me in this?

Comment: If you are filtering the records based on both the fields it will use the index for both the columns as composite otherwise it will filter the records based on first column only and will search sequentially for the second column which will add delay.
Try Explain your query.

Comment: EXPLAIN plan tells: Possible_key : BOOK_NO and PERIODIC_year , key= BOOK_NO , type = range;

Answer (score 0):

As Álvaro González said, you should use some sort of key (eg. a Primary Key).

Adding a Primary Key:

```
CREATE TABLE fa (
<your_id>,    
{...},
PRIMARY KEY(<your_id>),
{...}
)
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE fa (
<your_id> PRIMARY KEY,
{...}
)
```

It'd be a good idea to make your `PRIMARY KEY` `AUTO_INCREMENT` too for convenience, but this is not essenitial.

Comment: I only mentioned lack of PK as surprising omission in a relational database but I don't think it'd help a lot when searching by `BOOK_NO` and `periodic_year`.

Comment: @James Whiteley what is the use when i use update query like update tablename set dynamic_year= where book_no and period_year = '', and i have added indexing to both column which where clause has used. as i mentioned i cannot create primary key because it has many plenty of  duplicate values in it.